# OAuth2 authentication plugin for ServiceStack .NET Core

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, servicestack, .net-core

Apologies if this is already answered on this site or in the extensive ServiceStack documentation - I have looked, but if it does exist, I would appreciate a pointer!

I've been trying to knock up an example service stack (1.0.35) service which demonstrates the usage of OAuth2 using .NET core (not .NET 4.5.x).

I have found [this web page](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) and have added the AuthFeature plugin as described, which seems to be fine for the providers that are available.

**My question**: The Yahoo, OpenId, Google and LinkedIn providers don't appear part of the ServiceStack.Auth namespace (yet?). I have looked at the Servicestack.Authentication.OAuth2 NuGET package, but this appears to be targeted at .NET 4.6.x. Is this functionality available or on the roadmap for ServiceStack .NET core?

**Full Code repo of my demo app:**

```
namespace ServiceStackAuthTest1
{
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebHost host = new WebHostBuilder()
           .UseKestrel()
           .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .UseStartup<Startup>()
           .UseUrls("http://*:40000/")
           .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLogging();

    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseServiceStack((AppHostBase)Activator.CreateInstance<AppHost>());

        app.Run((RequestDelegate)(context => (Task)Task.FromResult<int>(0)));
    }

}

public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() 
        : base("My Test Service", typeof(MyService).GetAssembly())
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[]
            {
                new JwtAuthProvider(AppSettings)
                {
                    HashAlgorithm = "RS256",
                    PrivateKeyXml = AppSettings.GetString("PrivateKeyXml")
                },
                new ApiKeyAuthProvider(AppSettings), //Sign-in with API Key
                new CredentialsAuthProvider(), //Sign-in with UserName/Password credentials
                new BasicAuthProvider(), //Sign-in with HTTP Basic Auth
                new DigestAuthProvider(AppSettings), //Sign-in with HTTP Digest Auth
                new TwitterAuthProvider(AppSettings), //Sign-in with Twitter
                new FacebookAuthProvider(AppSettings), //Sign-in with Facebook
                //new YahooOpenIdOAuthProvider(AppSettings), //Sign-in with Yahoo OpenId
                //new OpenIdOAuthProvider(AppSettings), //Sign-in with Custom OpenId
                //new GoogleOAuth2Provider(AppSettings), //Sign-in with Google OAuth2 Provider
                //new LinkedInOAuth2Provider(AppSettings), //Sign-in with LinkedIn OAuth2 Provider
                new GithubAuthProvider(AppSettings), //Sign-in with GitHub OAuth Provider
                new YandexAuthProvider(AppSettings), //Sign-in with Yandex OAuth Provider        
                new VkAuthProvider(AppSettings), //Sign-in with VK.com OAuth Provider 
            }));
    }
}

public class MyService : Service
{

}
```

Comment: I am planning to write a .NET Core-compatible port of ServiceStack.Auth.OAuth2.OAuth2Provider as OSS but first I am looking to see if it's already been done. Anyone done this before?

Comment: In the meanwhile vote on https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/19534429-support-oauth2-on-net-core

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ServiceStack's OAuth2 depends on DotNetOpenAuth which unfortunately doesn't support .NET Core so there's currently no support for OAuth2.

Comment: That's fine (and thanks for an official answer!) - I am interested to know if there are any future plans to support these OAuth2 providers? 

I'm beginning to think that I could (should?) get a public Nginx gatekeeper/reverse proxy type of thing to handle the auth and just forward the relevant tokens to my internal service stack services.

Comment: @Jay we do want to support OAuth2 in .NET Core, just need to find the solution that works and best integrates with ServiceStack.

Comment: @mythz Any movement on this? Google Auth is the only thing preventing us from moving to .net core!

Comment: @JMK Not yet, please [submit a feature request on UserVoice](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests) so we can measure interest in this issue and you can get notified of updates.

Comment: People, when you need this feature vote for it on https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/19534429-support-oauth2-on-net-core

Comment: @mythz Just noticed you have started work on this and renewed my subscription, thanks!